# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl - which control to use in the .rc file ? - MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, resource-files

I am working on an MFC project with part of it requesting the user to choose a folder destination.

Right now, I have it implemented using a non-editable `CEdit` box whose value is set by the path chosen by the user, who chooses it by clicking a `CButton` button which calls the `CFolderPickerDialog` found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/993640/Using-MFC-CFolderPickerDialog).

However, it looks rather messy and I would prefer using the sleeker `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`, which from my research and understanding (and please do correct me if I am wrong about this), can make what is essentially one object with both the box that holds a string (in this case a folder path) and a button which opens up a folder browse dialog, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRcWa.png) one here, above the 100% in the linked image.

My trouble is implementing this in the `.rc` file. Other `C....` objects like `CEdit` or `CListBox` require the user to add them to the `.rc` file with `CONTROLS` found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-definition-statements). For example, `CEdit` uses `EDITTEXT` and `CListBox` uses `LISTBOX`.

My question is which control is used for `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` ?

Ideally, I could use a style in the `.rc` file to make the box un-editable, and can only be changed when the user browses for a folder. Then the box will contain the folder path.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just dragging a MFC EditBrowse Control from the Resource Editor?

[image]

In my RC file this control is defined like this:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE_LOCAL_BACKUP_FOLDER,"MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,18,173,327,14
```

And yes, I use it exactly for the purpose you described.

Comment: I will try this and update, one question: what is the ```0x80 ... ,14``` text at the end of the line ? Is it a style (which ? ) or something else

Comment: Also where did you get ```"MfcEditBrowse"``` from, I know the CONTROL control uses different texts even things like "Button" but I am not sure where I can find a list for them, I looked on docs.microsoft documentation but could not find anything even [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/control-control)

Comment: Also this is my first MFC project so I am unfamiliar with the resource editor or wizard, so I am doing it manually for now I suppose, any helpful links or pages that help with learning mfc and its editor ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa I put none of that text in. I simply dragged the control onto the dialog and adjusted the properties. The RC updates as you adjust properties.

Comment: @HusamChekfa Tge resource editor is fairly simply. There are many books out there you can find. You are going about this whole task the hard way IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The docs at [`CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=msvc-170) say to use an EDIT control in the dialog resource then to use `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` for the bound member.

All this would be easier to do with class wizard but can be accomplished manually as well.